# input type="password" on firefox mobile sending dots

Tags: android, html, forms, firefox

When using an  in a form, the password that gets sent to the server on Firefox mobile only consists of the ••• dots that are shown in the input field, while on other browsers the entered password gets sent.

Using this html code:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">

<head>
    <meta charset="UTF-8">
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0">
    <meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="ie=edge">
</head>

<body>
    <form action="/test">
        <input id="password" type="password" name="password" placeholder="Password" autocomplete="current-password">
        <button type="submit">Submit</button>
    </form>
</body>

</html>
```

When I serve this with `python -m http.server` and enter asdf on any Desktop browser or Chrome on Android, I get the `?password=asdf` query, while on Firefox Mobile 123.0 (Android) I get `?password=%E2%80%A2%E2%80%A2%E2%80%A2%E2%80%A2` i.e. the encoded ••••. How can I get it to send the password like the other browsers?

Answer (score 0):

this is URL encoded. This is a security measure to prevent the password from being easily readable you can use the `decodeURIComponent()` function to decode URL-encoded strings

in javaScript

```
const encodedPassword = '%E2%80%A2%E2%80%A2%E2%80%A2%E2%80%A2';
const decodedPassword = decodeURIComponent(encodedPassword);
console.log(decodedPassword);
```

in python

```
import urllib.parse
encoded_password = '%E2%80%A2%E2%80%A2%E2%80%A2%E2%80%A2'
decoded_password = urllib.parse.unquote(encoded_password)
print(decoded_password)
```

Comment: My problem is not the encoding, but the fact that it's not the password that's being sent: You enter asdf, but •••• is sent.

Comment: if this happening in firefox alone, then perhaps there is a technical bug in the application itself that will be fixed in future versions maybe